# MS Access 2003 - Is there a way to programmatically define the data for a chart?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

So I have some VBA for taking charts built with the Form's Chart Wizard, and automatically inserting it into PowerPoint Presentation slides. I use those chart-forms as sub forms within a larger forms that has parameters the user can select to determine what is on the chart. The idea is that the user can determine the parameter, build the chart to his/her liking, and click a button and have it in a ppt slide with the company's background template, blah blah blah.....

So it works, though it is very bulky in terms of the amount of objects I have to use to accomplish this.

I use expressions such as the following:

```
like forms!frmMain.Month&*
```

to get the input values into the saved queries, which was fine when i first started, but it went over so well and they want so many options, that it is driving the number of saved queries/objects up. I need several saved forms with charts because of the number of different types of charts I need to have this be able to handle.

SO FINALLY TO MY QUESTION:

I would much rather do all this on the fly with some VBA. I know how to insert list boxes, and text boxes on a form, and I know how to use SQL in VBA to get the values I want from tables/queries using VBA, I just don't know if there is some vba I can use to set the data values of the charts from a resulting recordset:

```
DIM rs AS DAO.Rescordset
DIM db AS DAO.Database
DIM sql AS String

sql = "SELECT TOP 5 Count(tblMain.TransactionID) AS Total, tblMain.Location FROM
tblMain WHERE (((tblMain.Month) = """ & me.txtMonth & """ )) ORDER BY Count 
(tblMain.TransactionID) DESC;"

set db = currentDB
set rs = db.OpenRecordSet(sql)

              rs.movefirst

            some kind of cool code in here to make this recordset
             the data of chart in frmChart ("Chart01")
```

thanks for your help. apologies for the length of the explanation.

Comment: Have you considered just hardwiring your graph's SQL to the control with the month in it? That is, replace """ & me.txtMonth & """ with [Forms!YourFormName!txtMonth] and then requery the graph to update it to reflect the current value in the month control.

Comment: so there are many parameters/controls from the form, the above was just for example sake. so having said that, is there a limit to the amount of expressions like the above that i can put in a SQL statement?? thanks David!

Comment: The limitations of that approach depend on the interaction of the criteria. If some are allowed to be blank, then you've potential problems. If they are all filled out, then it's pretty easy. The former problem can be worked around, but it can get pretty complicated and can be a real performance hog (particularly if you end up having to put criteria on expressions that have to be evaluated for each row, which means the indexes can't be used).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to change the dataset directly in vba as I have managed to do it. However the performance is not so good so I went back to filling the results to a temp table and basing the graph on that ( see my only asked stackoverflow question) however if the dataset is quite small then you can certainly make it work. I'm not in the office but if you want code I can post on Monday

EDIT: here is the old code module I used. This is the full thing but the key part you are going to be looking at is the part about opening the datasheet of the graph and then changing the value of it like this .cells(1,0)="badger".

I enevtly dumped this method and went with a temp table as in my app the graph is redraw quite a lot and I needed to go for the fastest possible method to give a "real time" feel to it but it might be just fine for your needs

```
Public Sub Draw_graph(strGraph_type As String)
Dim objGraph As Object
Dim objDS As Object
Dim i As Byte


On Error GoTo Error_trap

Dim lRT_actual As Long
Dim lRT_forecast As Long
Dim Start_time As Long
Dim aCell_buffer(49, 4) As Variant
Me.acxProgress_bar.Visible = True
Me.acxProgress_bar.Value = 0
Set objGraph = Me.oleCall_graph.Object
Set objDS = objGraph.Application.datasheet
Start_time = GetTime()
With objDS
    .cells.Clear
    Select Case strGraph_type
        Case Is = "Agents"
            '**************************
            '** Draw the agent graph **
            '**************************
            .cells(1, 1) = "Start Time"
            .cells(1, 2) = "Provided"
            .cells(1, 3) = "Required"
            .cells(1, 4) = "Actual Required"
            For i = 1 To 48
                .cells(i + 1, 1) = Format(DateAdd("n", (i - 1) * 15, "08:00:00"), "HHMM")
                If Me.Controls("txtAgents_pro_" & i) > 0 Then
                    .cells(i + 1, 2) = Me.Controls("txtAgents_pro_" & i) + Me.Controls("txtAgents_add_" & i)
                Else
                    .cells(i + 1, 2) = 0
                End If
                If Me.Controls("txtAgents_req_" & i) > 0 Then
                    .cells(i + 1, 3) = Me.Controls("txtAgents_req_" & i)
                End If

                If Me.Controls("txtActual_" & i) > 0 Then
                    .cells(i + 1, 4) = Erlang_Agents(Me.txtServiceLevel, Me.txtServiceTime, Me.Controls("txtActual_" & i) * 4, Me.txtAVHT + CLng(Nz(Me.txtDaily_AVHT_DV, 0)))
                End If


                'update the progress bar
                If Me.acxProgress_bar.Value + 2 < 100 Then
                    Me.acxProgress_bar.Value = Me.acxProgress_bar.Value + 2
                Else
                    Me.acxProgress_bar.Value = 90
                End If
            Next i
        Case Is = "Calls"
            '**************************
            '** Draw the Calls graph **
            '**************************
            .cells(1, 1) = "Start Time"
            .cells(1, 2) = "Forecast"
            .cells(1, 3) = "Actual"
            For i = 1 To 48
                .cells(i + 1, 1) = Format(DateAdd("n", (i - 1) * 15, "08:00:00"), "HHMM")
                If Me.Controls("txtForecast_" & i) > 0 Then
                    .cells(i + 1, 2) = Me.Controls("txtForecast_" & i)
                Else
                    .cells(i + 1, 2) = 0
                End If
                If Me.Controls("txtActual_" & i) > 0 Then
                    .cells(i + 1, 3) = Me.Controls("txtActual_" & i)
                End If
                If Me.acxProgress_bar.Value + 2 < 100 Then
                    Me.acxProgress_bar.Value = Me.acxProgress_bar.Value + 2
                Else
                    Me.acxProgress_bar.Value = 90
                End If
            Next i

        Case Is = "Call Deviation"
            '**************************
            '** Draw the Call Deviation graph **
            '**************************
            .cells(1, 1) = "Start Time"
            .cells(1, 2) = "Deviation"
            lRT_actual = 0
            lRT_forecast = 0
            For i = 1 To 48
                lRT_actual = lRT_actual + Me.Controls("txtActual_" & i)
                lRT_forecast = lRT_forecast + Me.Controls("txtForecast_" & i)
                .cells(i + 1, 1) = Format(DateAdd("n", (i - 1) * 15, "08:00:00"), "HHMM")

                .cells(i + 1, 2) = lRT_actual - lRT_forecast

                If Me.acxProgress_bar.Value + 2 < 100 Then
                    Me.acxProgress_bar.Value = Me.acxProgress_bar.Value + 2
                Else
                    Me.acxProgress_bar.Value = 90
                End If
            Next i

        Case Is = "Call Deviation %"
            '**************************
            '** Draw the Call Deviation % graph **
            '**************************

            .cells(1, 1) = "Start Time"
            .cells(1, 2) = "Deviation"
            lRT_actual = 0
            lRT_forecast = 0


            For i = 1 To 48
                lRT_actual = lRT_actual + Me.Controls("txtActual_" & i)
                lRT_forecast = lRT_forecast + Me.Controls("txtForecast_" & i)
                .cells(i + 1, 1) = Format(DateAdd("n", (i - 1) * 15, "08:00:00"), "HHMM")
                If lRT_forecast > 0 Then
                    .cells(i + 1, 2) = (lRT_actual - lRT_forecast) / lRT_forecast
                End If

                If Me.acxProgress_bar.Value + 2 < 100 Then
                    Me.acxProgress_bar.Value = Me.acxProgress_bar.Value + 2
                Else
                    Me.acxProgress_bar.Value = 90
                End If
            Next i



        Case Is = "SLA"
            '**************************
            '*** Draw the SLA graph ***
            '**************************
            .cells(1, 1) = "Start Time"
            .cells(1, 2) = "SLA"
            .cells(1, 3) = "Actual SLA"
            For i = 1 To 48
                .cells(i + 1, 1) = Format(DateAdd("n", (i - 1) * 15, "08:00:00"), "HHMM")
                If Me.Controls("txtSLA_" & i) > 0 Then
                    .cells(i + 1, 2) = Me.Controls("txtSLA_" & i) / 100
                Else
                    .cells(i + 1, 2) = 0
                End If
                If Me.Controls("txtActual_SLA_" & i) > 0 Then
                    .cells(i + 1, 3) = Me.Controls("txtActual_SLA_" & i)
                End If
                If Me.acxProgress_bar.Value + 2 < 100 Then
                    Me.acxProgress_bar.Value = Me.acxProgress_bar.Value + 2
                Else
                    Me.acxProgress_bar.Value = 90
                End If
            Next i

    End Select
End With

Set objDS = Nothing
Set objGraph = Nothing
Me.acxProgress_bar.Visible = False


Exit Sub

Error_trap:
DoCmd.Hourglass False

MsgBox "An error happened in sub Draw_graph, error description, " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Tracker 3"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

One very easy way of doing this is to base the chart on a query and update the query, for example:

```
strSQL = "SELECT ..."

QueryName = "qryByHospital"

If IsNull(DLookup("Name", "MsysObjects", "Name='" & QueryName & "'")) Then
    CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef QueryName, strSQL
Else
    CurrentDb.QueryDefs(QueryName).SQL = strSQL
End If

DoCmd.OpenReport "rptChartByHospital", acViewPreview
```

Comment: Just to emphasize what @Remou says, this is actually the only way to change the resultset behind a graph in Access, except if you rely on the Access/Jet expression service for criteria. I encountered this c. 1996, and it hasn't ever changed. And yes, it sucks.

Comment: does this method still require me to save a 'query' as an object? do i need to define 'QueryName' as a string? thanks as always Remou?

Comment: In this example, QueryName is a string. It will create the query if it is missing, but the most convenient thing to do is to create a suitable query and build a chart on a form or report, then add code to change the SQL, as illustrated above. Remember that the query is changed permanently.