# How to change querydef sql programmatically in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have done

```
Dim qd as querydef
set qd = Querydefs("MyQuery")
qd.sql = "..."
```

In debug qd.sql has been updated but the physical MyQuery still contains the old sql.

How to update this physical query ?

The source code given by microsoft here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177500.aspx

doesn't work either.

Comment: The `CreateQueryDef` method appears to be the correct way to do this.  It accepts a SQL string, and creates the QueryDef.

Comment: Yes that's the reason I don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: If the query already exists, you can edit it, otherwise you can use CreateQueyDef. I suspect the problem may be in the SQL, because this is something I use regularly and with a number of versions of Access.

Comment: FWIW, I consider it a very rare circumstance that *requires* the changing of the SQL of a saved QueryDef. In general, if you're changing the WHERE clause, you've got a bad design (though there are specific situations where it's obviously useful, they aren't that commeon).

Comment: Changing the query SQL is extremely useful for graphs and output of formatted HTML, especially if this involves complicated crosstabs with user input.

Comment: Not so "very rare" or such "bad design", to quote DW Fenton "... this is actually the only way to change the resultset behind a graph ..." -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388691/ms-access-2003-is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-define-the-data-for-a-chart/2389276#2389276

Comment: I am aware of the limitations of graphs and have done it myself. But MS Graph is almost unusable in Access in any event, and I don't think that many people use it (it's quite torturous to do so, in fact). Because of that, I didn't think it important to mention that exception, because it's a pretty narrow one.

Comment: I don't know what you mean about "formatted HTML" though. Can you say more or point me at something that explains how that needs to be tied to a saved QueryDef?

Comment: Very well, HTML. It is possible to further query a saved query and Access is a useful tool for analyzing data, hence "especially if this involves complicated crosstabs". The implication of your statement was that changing a querydef using code was nearly always bad design. Data analysis is a common enough use for Access that immediately came to mind.

Comment: I don't see how my comment, which allows for exceptions, implies "nearly always." It *is* bad design if it's not necessary, and it's good design if it *is* necessary. We don't know enough about the present context to say which it is here, but in general (as I said in my first comment), I'd avoid altering a saved QueryDef except in the exceptional cases you've outlined where it's the only way to do the job. I still don't know what your reference to HTML is about, though.

Answer (score 10):

You should not use SET except with objects. You need an object for QueryDefs, so:

```
Dim qd As QueryDef
Set qd = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("MyQuery")
qd.SQL = "SELECT Category FROM Categories"
```

Ensure that the SQL works, or it will error out.

Comment: yes it was a mistypo. But even above doesn't work.

My SQL works for sure as it executes when I use DoCmd.RunSQL qd.SQL

Comment: Are you *sure* the SQL executes correction with RunSQL? If you have SetWarnings turned off, you'll never know if there's an error. The only way to check is to paste the SQL into a new QueryDef in the QBE and try to run that in the QBE.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but found it when I was looking for a solution to a similar problem. So anyone finding this thread for the same reason may find my solution helpful.

In my case the problem was due to using workspace begintrans/commitrans for a range of action queries, plus some select queries displayed in a form for the user to review before continuing (using a subform with query.nameofquery as the sourceobject)- the querydef object was not being updated until the committrans code was run.

Nesting Begintrans did not work for me (tho' I may have missed something) so I had to modify the code to go through all the confirmations first and then start begintrans